# Exact size of makebox

Tags: koma-script, size, colorbox

I am trying to create a page layout, where the page number is shown on the right margin in a white textcolor on a black background.

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[headwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\textcolor{white}}

\chead{}
\ohead{\leftmark\quad\colorbox{black}{\makebox[2cm][l]{\pagemark}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\colorbox{black}{\makebox[2cm]{\textcolor{white}{1-2-3}}}
\lipsum[1-11]

\end{document}
```

That works already -- at least almost. However, I have two questions.

1. The size of the `\makebox` field does not seem to be exact. The left border of the black background seems to be a little bit more to the left than the right text border. When loading the generated PDF in Affinity Photo, the size of both `\makebox`es is about 2.2 cm instead of 2.0 cm.
2. Is it possible to move the command for the black background into the `\setkomafont{pagenumber}` expression or to a `\renewcommand*{\pagemark}...` command? This would facilitate defining different headers using the same black box page number.

Comment: Welcome! The size of `\makebox` is exact, it's `\colorbox` that adds padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep\relax]{...}` to adjust the width of the box:

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,
  %showframe% show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage[headwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[\pagemark]{\leftmark\quad\pagemark}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \colorbox{black}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep\relax][l]{%
      \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}%
}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep\relax]{\textcolor{white}{1-2-3}}}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```

Result with geometry option `showframe`:

[image]

[image]

Or you could use `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` to move the page number box in the margin:

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,
  %showframe% show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- changed
\usepackage{xcolor}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead[{\makebox[0pt][l]{\pagemark}}]{\leftmark\quad\makebox[0pt][l]{\pagemark}}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \colorbox{black}{%
    \makebox[2cm][l]{%
      \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\thepage}%
}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep\relax]{\textcolor{white}{1-2-3}}}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```

Or you could declare a new page style layer and add it to the layer page styles:

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,
  showframe% show the page layout
]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- changed
\usepackage{xcolor}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark\quad}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  head,
  addhoffset=\textwidth,
  oddpage,
  contents=\colorbox{black}{\makebox[5cm][l]{\pagemark}}
]{pagenumber}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{plain.scrheadings}{pagenumber}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr2cm-2\fboxsep]{\textcolor{white}{1-2-3}}}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the `\colorbox` padding to 0pt, LaTeX also removes the padding above and below the text. I think that the best or at least the easiest way is eyeballing the padding and correct it accordingly.

I also found a solution to my 2nd question.

This is the revised script:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[headwidth=paper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\automark[chapter]{chapter}

\renewcommand*{\pagemark}{\colorbox{black}{\makebox[1.85cm][l]{\normalfont\textcolor{white}\thepage}}}

\chead{}
\ohead{\leftmark\quad\pagemark}
\cfoot[]{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-11]

\end{document}
```

The white page number on the black background can now be easily reused with the simple `\pagemark` argument.

I also added `\cfoot[]{}` to remove the previously invisible page number (because it was white) from the footer.